# ASP.NET Core SignInWithClaimsAsync

Tags: c#, authentication, external

I use an external authentication mechanism.
In the Startup file I configure as follows the external authentication:

```
AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>...);
```

Afterwards I changed the ExternalLogin.cshtml.
There I do some stuff to retrieve the Access control and do after that the following code.

```
await _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(userDb, false, claims);
```

After some time, I'm logged in but the server losses the claims.
How can I configure, that the claims should be available until the user logged out?

Best regards